# Can't convert string to integer in shell

Tags: bash, shell, carriage-return

I have a file `test.csv` with numbers:

```
>cat test.csv
32
23
45
```

I store the first value in a variable:

```
>e=$(cat test.csv | head -n 1)
>echo $e
32
```

However, I can't do arithmetic with this number, I have tried converting it to integer as explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232384/argument-string-to-integer-in-bash?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):

```
>echo "$((e + 1))"
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

EDIT: Issue might have to do with whitespaces, that I can't delete:

```
>c="32"
>echo $c | wc -c
3
>echo $c | wc -c
4
>echo $c | tr -d '[:space]' | wc -c
4
```

Comment: Check your file for special characters: `cat -A file` or `cat -v file`

Comment: Looks like the file has DOS line endings. Notice the `'\r'` forcing the final `")` back to the front of the line in the error message? You can use `dos2unix filename` to fix that issue. A `hexdump -Cv filename` will show the `0xb` (13) character.

Comment: there is some strange `^M character` at the end of each line

Comment: The `^M` is the *carriage-return*. (DOS or Mac - pre OSX line ending) (or just copy/paste the file from what you posted above which should strip the carriage returns as well, e.g. select your text above, `rm filename` then `vi filename`, `i` and `middle-mouse`, then `esc` and `:wq`

Comment: `dos2unix filename` solved it. Thanks!